# What's the proper pluralization of this linking verb? Did I violate the subject-verb agreement law?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

This is the quote I'm having trouble with.

> Help me prioritize my tasks. By "tasks," what I really mean is
> programming languages.

I'm particularly confused in the line where I say, "what I really mean is programming language**s**." It just feels stilted to say "what I really mean **are** programming languages,"  since the initial declaration of what is being referred to here was singular. Did I do it right, or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: Subject agreement has to be with the **subject**. And the subject  here, in a _Wh_-cleft sentence, is a clause: _what I really mean_. All clauses are automatically singular, by default. It **should** feel stilted to say _are_ here; in fact, it's ungramamtical.

Comment: A word-as-a-word is a singular entity taking singular agreement. 'Men are coming over the hill.' but '_Men_ is a three-letter word.' ... 'What _tasks_ means [in this instance] **is** ....' // '... my intended sense of _tasks_ here **is** ....'

Answer (score -1):

> ... **what I really mean** is programming languages.

This is a pseudo-cleft construction, where the subject (in bold) is a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction.

It can be paraphrased as "that which I really mean", where singular agreement is clearly appropriate.

Generally, the verb agrees with the head of the subject for number purposes, but where the predicate includes a predicative, there are many instances where predicate and predicand differ in grammatical number, for example:

*The only **thing** we need now is some new **curtains**.*

*The major **asset** of the team is its word-class opening **bowlers**.*